# How to verify user is authenticated entire app Xamarin Form

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

I'm new with Xamarin form, my question is how can I check user is logged in for entire app, example every time when users go to a new page, it checks for authent. I tried successfully for every page check for auth but is there any another ways to do it? I did some research on internet and some said that i have to auth on the App.cs on `OnStart()` but the event is not raise when i go to the next page, it starts only when user open the app.

Here is my code, I'm using Google auth.

On the logged in page (HomePage):

```
public HomePage(NetworkAuthData networkAuthData)
{
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(networkAuthData.Id))
        {
            //Always require user authentication
            //Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new SocialLoginPage(oAuth2Service));
        }
        else
        {
            BindingContext = networkAuthData;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

It works but when i move these code to app.cs on `OnStart()` it just run once when opened the app.

Comment: you should not need to check on every page.  Generally just check in OnStart and OnResume, unless you think its possible their auth status could change while they're actively using the app

Comment: hi, my scenario is login page -> homepage -> another pages. when i navigate user to those pages the Onstart event not raise to check user auth. so i have to check for my home page and rest of another pages

Comment: that's what I'm saying, why do you need to check on EVERY page?  If the user is auth on page1, why would that suddenly change when they move to page2?

Comment: i just think some how, unauth users can navigate to the page2. can it happens?

Comment: I don't see how